# Is there a way to search for packages that contain a specific file using brew?

Tags: file, search, package, homebrew

How can I search for packages that contain a specific file using brew?

In some package managers it is possible to search for files inside of a package before installing it but i could not figure out how to do it using brew.

An example would be something like this on ubuntu:

```sh
$ dpkg -S /bin/ls
coreutils: /bin/ls
```

Ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file

Comment: Seems not... https://superuser.com/q/781693

Comment: Thank you for checking into and confirming that it was not a simple oversight.